# how to listen if button from toolbar in tinymce is click and prevent default function if needed

Tags: image, plugins, tinymce

Hi there especial I am struggle to prevent allowed pit more then 3 picture in text so I would like to listen when button image from plug-ins in tinymce is click and then I could prevent default process if is more then 2 picture already in text , please  if any one know how to do it ?

I tried in

```
tinymce.init({

setup : function(editor) {


editor.on('click', function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
});
}
});
```

but not any comment fire when i  click on image plugin button

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own plugin?

I used the following code inside wordpress admin to triger the upload media popup:

```
// Init tinyMCE
tinymce.init({
    editor_selector: 'nwac_editor_' + nextPlusSignId,
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    media_buttons: false,
    menubar: false,
    relative_urls: false,
    toolbar: 'undo redo formatselect bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify bullist numlist outdent indent plusimage',
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addButton('plusimage', {
            icon: 'image',
            tooltip: 'Insert/edit image',
            onclick: function() {

            // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
            if (file_frame) {
                file_frame.open();
                return;
            }

            // Create the media frame.
            file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                title: 'Choose an image for the plus sign',
                button: {
                    text: 'Insert selected',
                },
                multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
            });

            // When an image is selected, run a callback.
            file_frame.on('select', function() {
                // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
                attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

                //console.log(attachment);

                editor.insertContent('<img src="' + attachment.url + '" data-mce-src="' + attachment.url + '" alt="' + attachment.alt + '">');

                return;
            });

            // Finally, open the modal
            file_frame.open();
            }
        });
    },
    content_css: nw.baseurl + '/skins/wordpress/wp-content.css',
    body_class: 'mce-content-body nwac_plus_signs_' + nextPlusSignId + '_template post-type-products post-status-publish mceContentBody webkit wp-editor wp-autoresize html4-captions has-focus',

});
```